# Como usar joblib no Python para paralelismo?

Tags: python, paralelismo, job

Estava tentando utilizar o `Thread` do Python para paralelizar o meu código porém me esbarrei em um problema: quando mando criar as Threads, a quantidade delas ultrapassa 1.000 Threads facilmente, o que, a partir de 140, todas começam a dar erro.
Pesquisando um bocado eu achei o `joblib`, mas não achei nenhum exemplo de como usar com funções minhas... Por exemplo, quero uma função, criada por mim, que tem 3 parâmetros, e essa função está dentro de um for, que será repetido milhares de vezes...

```
repeticoes = 10000
for i in range(repeticoes):
    minha_funcao(data[i], top, param3)
```

Eu usaria assim?

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=4, verbose=1)(delayed(minha_funcao)(data[i], top, param3) for i in range(repeticoes))
```

Answer (score 1):

Threads criam uma "linha de processamento paralelo" dentro do seu programa - mas não fazem mágica: todas usam recursos e fazem exatamente o que você manda.

Garantir que um dado programa não crie mais que um número ótimo de threads (que dependendo da natureza do programa pode variar - um programa que seja intensivo em cálculo e uso de processamento não se beneficiará de mais que uma thread por núcleo lógico da sua CPU(*) - enquanto que threads que dependam de tempo de resposta a requisições de rede ou a periféricos podem se beneficiar de um número maior).

- Em Python puro também não resolve muito ter várias threads se o problema for processamento - apenas uma thread de código Python é executada por vez, não importa quantos núcleos físicos você tenha, devido a uma característica na implementação da linguagem

De qualquer forma, uma lógica do tipo: "se o número total de threads já em execução for maior que 'MAX_THREADS' (um número que você avaliou ser o ótimo), apenas anote a tarefa, e a execute numa das threds já criadas quando uma das tarefas em execução for concluída". Essa lógica não é tão difícil de implementar de forma simples - mas se torna complicada a medida que queremos o máximo de eficiência, e dar conta de todos os "corner cases" e sempre fazer a "coisa certa".

Por conta disso, a biblioteca padrão do Python (a partir da versão 3.2) implementa objetos conhecidos como "Futures" e "threadpools" - que implementam exatamente essa lógica. Sugiro ler sobre ["concurrent.futures"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) e implementar o seu programa usando `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. (E se o seu problema for 
intensivo em processamento, `ProcessPoolExecutor` - dessa forma todos os núcleos do processador podem ser usados)

Comment: Então, a ideia é fazer o meu código funcionar na minha máquina atual, mas será colocado em produção mesmo em um servidor com muitos núcleos (mais de 64 só em 1 nó, que talvez utilizarei somente esse). Tenho muita leitura de arquivos e gravação em banco, por isso pensei na concorrência. Acha que convém manter essa biblioteca que você sugere?